# pyjnius "cannot find class" error

Tags: java, android, python, kivy, pyjnius

I am trying to make a Bluetooth app with Kivy so I need to use java classes, I get this error message when I use Pyjnius

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omer Akbas\Desktop\My Apps (Kivy)\First\main.py", line 3, in             
<module>
    BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jnius\reflect.py", line 158, in 
  autoclass
    c = find_javaclass(clsname)
  File "jnius\jnius_export_func.pxi", line 25, in jnius.find_javaclass
JavaException: Class not found 'android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a Kivy app, pyjnius is installed in the APK automatically as a dependency of Kivy, so you don't have to do anything special beyond the normal [Programming Guide » Create a package for Android](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) documentation.